# Python GDAL: Georeference array using other file for projection

Tags: python, gdal

I have an array of data, for each point I know the latitude and longitude of that point, and I'd like to write the data to a GTiff with projection taken from another file. How do I properly georeference the new file?

This is what I'm attempting just now:

```
import numpy as np
import gdal
from gdalconst import *
from osgeo import osr

def GetGeoInfo(FileName):
    SourceDS = gdal.Open(FileName, GA_ReadOnly)
    GeoT = SourceDS.GetGeoTransform()
    Projection = osr.SpatialReference()
    Projection.ImportFromWkt(SourceDS.GetProjectionRef())
    return GeoT, Projection

def CreateGeoTiff(Name, Array, driver, 
                  xsize, ysize, GeoT, Projection):
    DataType = gdal.GDT_Float32
    NewFileName = Name+'.tif'
    # Set up the dataset
    DataSet = driver.Create( NewFileName, xsize, ysize, 1, DataType )
            # the '1' is for band 1.
    DataSet.SetGeoTransform(GeoT)
    DataSet.SetProjection( Projection.ExportToWkt() )
    # Write the array
    DataSet.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( Array )
    return NewFileName

def ReprojectCoords(x, y,src_srs,tgt_srs):
    trans_coords=[]
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation( src_srs, tgt_srs)
    x,y,z = transform.TransformPoint(x, y)
    return x, y

# Some Data
Data = np.random.rand(5,6)
Lats = np.array([-5.5, -5.0, -4.5, -4.0, -3.5])
Lons = np.array([135.0, 135.5, 136.0, 136.5, 137.0, 137.5])

# A raster file that exists in the same approximate aregion.
RASTER_FN = 'some_raster.tif'

# Open the raster file and get the projection, that's the
# projection I'd like my new raster to have, it's 'projected',
# i.e. x, y values are numbers of pixels.
GeoT, TargetProjection, DataType = GetGeoInfo(RASTER_FN)
# Meanwhile my raster is currently in geographic coordinates.
SourceProjection = TargetProjection.CloneGeogCS()

# Get the corner coordinates of my array
LatSize, LonSize = len(Lats), len(Lons)
LatLow, LatHigh = Lats[0], Lats[-1]
LonLow, LonHigh = Lons[0], Lons[-1]
# Reproject the corner coordinates from geographic
# to projected...
TopLeft = ReprojectCoords(LonLow, LatHigh, SourceProjection, TargetProjection)
BottomLeft = ReprojectCoords(LonLow, LatLow, SourceProjection, TargetProjection)
TopRight = ReprojectCoords(LonHigh, LatHigh, SourceProjection, TargetProjection)
# And define my Geotransform
GeoTNew = [TopLeft[0],  (TopLeft[0]-TopRight[0])/(LonSize-1), 0,
           TopLeft[1], 0, (TopLeft[1]-BottomLeft[1])/(LatSize-1)]

# I want a GTiff
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
# Create the new file...
NewFileName = CreateGeoTiff('Output', Data, driver, LatSize, LonSize, GeoTNew, TargetProjection)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you use `SourceProjection = TargetProjection.CloneGeogCS()`, dont you just want to interpolate your data values to your target grid? Reprojecting with a osr.CoordinateTransformation isnt usefull for rasters/grids since your source and target grid are probably not 'aligned', so some form of interpolation needs to be done if you want a filled target grid.

Comment: @RutgerKassies Yes I'm aware that reprojecting will probably result in some form of interpolation, but over a small area that probably won't be too critical. I just want to save my array in a form so that I can open it in QGIS with my other raster files.

Comment: I wrote this as another question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58517/python-gdal-save-array-as-raster-with-projection-from-other-file/58551?noredirect=1#58551) and then for some reason that question vanished from my profile, so I assumed I'd failed to click save or something and rewrote it here. Now the original has turned up, with an answer, perhaps someone with the requisite reptation could mark this question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is save the data to a raster for use in QGIS, you can simply construct a new Geotiff (or any other GDAL format) from your data. There is no need for a 'target raster' unless you want to do some form of reprojection or interpolation.

Here is an example:

```
import gdal
import osr
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(5,6)
lats = np.array([-5.5, -5.0, -4.5, -4.0, -3.5])
lons = np.array([135.0, 135.5, 136.0, 136.5, 137.0, 137.5])

xres = lons[1] - lons[0]
yres = lats[1] - lats[0]

ysize = len(lats)
xsize = len(lons)

ulx = lons[0] - (xres / 2.)
uly = lats[-1] - (yres / 2.)

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds = driver.Create('D:\\test.tif', xsize, ysize, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

# this assumes the projection is Geographic lat/lon WGS 84
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

gt = [ulx, xres, 0, uly, 0, yres ]
ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)

outband = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(data)

ds = None
```

In this example i assumed that your lat/lon's refer to the center of a pixel, since GDAL works with the edge, adding half a pixelsize is necessary.